# I have a program with string literals to specify optional command line arguments. How to process these optional command line arguments in c?

Tags: c, command-line

Below is the syntax for my command line arguments.

```C
./main [-var1 value] [-var2 value] [-var3 value]
```

`var1`,`var2`  and `var3`  are strings. 
 for ex:  `var1` is aaa,  `var2` is bbb, and  `var3` is ccc.

However for a similar case with single characters options, for example `a`, `b` and `c` as shown below

```C
./main [-a value] [-b value] [-c value]
```

`getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:c:");` can be used. Is there a similar way to process `var1`,`var2`  and `var3` for my program.

Comment: Use getopt only. Have internal lookup for  options -A gets value of var1 , -B gets value  of var2 like that you can use options A-Z and a-z.

Comment: what if options are strings?

Comment: As @serge pointed out go for **getopt_long**. Which gives you flexibility to use both single char literals and strings as arguments. Many conventional programs provide both ways for specifying arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[man getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) is your friend!

`getopt` is the historical function that only processes single letter options, but it was extended with two companions:

- `getopt_long`: accept single letter options command starting with one single dash (`-a`) or multi-letter ones starting with two (`--action`)
- `getopt_long_only`: accept multi-letters options starting with one or two dashes (`--action` or `-action`)

(Following is just extracts from man page)

The signature for the latter two is :

```
int getopt_long(int argc, char * const argv[],
       const char *optstring,
       const struct option *longopts, int *longindex);
```

Where `longopts` is a pointer to the first element of an array of struct option declared in  as

```
struct option {
    const char *name;
    int         has_arg;
    int        *flag;
    int         val;
};
```

(The last element of the array has to be filled with zeros)

If `longindex` is not NULL, it points to a variable which is set to the index of the long option relative to `longopts`.